# Unable to completely change jquery class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, emoji

I am trying to make an emoji system whereby a file called emoji.css willm store the emojis.The names of all the emoji's are stored in a really javascript array although slightly altered.When users input a emoji text
(something like :emoji: ,:another-emoji:)Javascript should check if it that text is in the emoji array,if it is,it will be automatically turned into an emoji.

*Atleast that is what I'm trying to do*

This is the steps of what is supposed to happen

1. Page loads
2. User inputs in input with class 'input'
3. If the text  is in the array called 
   `emoji`,javascript

   ```
    i.Alerts the name of the input

    ii.Says 'it is in array'

    iii.Copy the text into a div with class 
       `see`

    iv.Text in div automatically becomes an array`
   ```

And I think that is where the problem is.

In the `emoji.css` file all emoji have classes with names like  `em em-abc`,`em em-woman`  but when users want to call an emoji, they must input a text with a `:` in the front and back like `:abc:`,`:woman:` so jquery should automatically change that input string(`:abc:`) to emoji.css class(em em-abc) and I used this line of code to do that

`$(".see").addClass("em em-"+$(".see").html().split(":").pop()).removeClass(".see");`

here is my full code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Rad emojis</title>
  <style>
  div {
    color: blue;
  }
  span {
    color: red;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <link href="emoji.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
 <div class ="see em-abc"></div>

 <input class="input">
 <div class ="see"></div>
  <div class ="see2"></div>
    <div class ="see3"></div>

<div class="add"></div>



<script>
var emoji = [ ":abc:", ":woman",":eye:", <!--it was much longer than this--> ];

var input=$(".input");
var input2=$(".input").val();



 $(input).change(function(){

$(".see").html( $(".input").val());


if(jQuery.inArray($(".input").val(), emoji) != -1) {

var see="."+$(".see").html();
$(".see2").html(see);

var classs =see+"";

alert($(".see").html());

var real=$(".see").html().split(":").pop();
$(".see3").html(real);


 $(".see").toggleClass("em em-"+$(".see").html().split(":").pop());

    $(".see").addClass("em em-"+$(".see").html().split(":").pop()).removeClass(".see");

    alert("is in array");
    alert($(".see").html());
} else {
    alert("is NOT in array");


} 

});






</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you remove a class using the removeClass method, you have to omit the dot.

Simply use

```
    $(".see").addClass("em em"+$(".see").html().split(":").pop()).removeClass("see");
```